# How can I disable JDWP service?

Tags: security, jdwp

I am getting Java Debug Wire Protocol Remote Code Execution  Vulnerability in one of the servers. How can I disable the service?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read this post first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And post some code that you have written so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late update, My issue was resolved after doing a cleanup of Tomcat configuration.